# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol / real time events not showing

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am logging HTTP POST requests from an embedded app using C code and seeing real-time events show up for one GA Account but not for another.

In both cases, the events turn up in the App Overview the following day as registered messages so the posting appears to be working. I am not however seeing the events turn up in the Real-Time section.

Notes:

  i) The Client ID is the same GUID in both cases [cid=35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b]

  ii) The only difference is the Tracking Code [tid=UA-XXXX-YY]

  iii) I understand the parameters "ev" and "el" are not necessary (and inserting them makes no difference)

  iv) Inserting the "an" parameter (e.g. an=MyApp) causes the event to show up in real-time; but removing the an=MyApp makes the event NOT show up as a real time event (but it does show up the following day as a registered event)

Any ideas what is going on here?

[As an aside (and although this should not cause any difference), I have enabled the GA API in the Developer Console and I am using the same DeveloperConsole-generated Client ID in both cases.]

EDITED:
Here is a representative snippet of the HTTP post:-

```
static BYTE ServerName[] = "www.google-analytics.com";
static WORD ServerPort = 80;
static BYTE GAClientID[] = "35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b";
static BYTE GATrackingCode[] = "UA-XXXXXXX-Y";
static ROM BYTE ContentLength[4];

strcpy(pPayloadBuffer, (ROM BYTE*)"v=1");
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, (ROM BYTE*)"&tid=");
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, (ROM BYTE*)GATrackingCode);
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, (ROM BYTE*)"&cid=");
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, (ROM BYTE*)GAClientID);

strcat(pPayloadBuffer, (ROM BYTE*)"&an=MyApp2&t=pageview&dp=Test");

strcat(pPayloadBuffer, (ROM BYTE*)"&t=event&ev=55&el=label&cd2=");

// get SNTP time and convert to struct tm
dwSNTPseconds = SNTPGetUTCSeconds();
timeNow = gmtime((const time_t*)&dwSNTPseconds);

// inspect values in tm struct
sec = timeNow->tm_sec;
min = timeNow->tm_min;
hour = timeNow->tm_hour;
day = timeNow->tm_mday;
month = timeNow->tm_mon;
year = timeNow->tm_year + 1900;

// years
uitoa(year, sBuffer);
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, sBuffer);

// months
if (month<10) {
    strcat(pPayloadBuffer, "0");
}
uitoa(month, sBuffer);
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, sBuffer);

// days
if (day<10) {
    strcat(pPayloadBuffer, "0");
}
uitoa(day, sBuffer);
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, sBuffer);

// hours
if (hour<10) {
    strcat(pPayloadBuffer, "0");
}
uitoa(hour, sBuffer);
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, sBuffer);

// minutes
if (min<10) {
    strcat(pPayloadBuffer, "0");
}
uitoa(min, sBuffer);
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, sBuffer);

// seconds
if (sec<10) {
    strcat(pPayloadBuffer, "0");
}
uitoa(sec, sBuffer);
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, sBuffer);

// Temperature
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, (ROM BYTE*)"&cm1=");
uitoa(gTemperature, tmpString);
strcat(pPayloadBuffer, tmpString);

lenPayload = strlen(pPayloadBuffer);

// Place the application protocol data into the transmit buffer
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"POST /collect HTTP/1.1\r\n");
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"Host: ");
TCPPutString(MySocket, ServerName);
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"\r\n");
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n");
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"Content-Length: ");
uitoa(lenPayload, (BYTE*)ContentLength);
TCPPutString(MySocket, (BYTE*)ContentLength);
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"\r\n");
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"Accept-Language: en-us \r\n");
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate \r\n");
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"Connection: Keep-Alive \r\n\r\n");
TCPPutString(MySocket, pPayloadBuffer);

// end of line
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"\r\n");
TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"\r\n");
// Send the packet
TCPFlush(MySocket);
```

Comment: any chance you can post a full example of the HTTP post? Is this a web analytics account or a application analytics account?

Comment: Account1: Web, Account2: App, Account3: Web. Only Account1 shows real-time events.    Added example of HTTP POST in above post

Comment: for app accounts its &t=screenview not &t=pageview

Comment: check my answer below please remember to except it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer I am just trying to help debugging:

For app accounts its &t=`screenview` not &t=pageview

For app accounts the following are undocumented required fields

- an –  Application name   example:  an=My%20Awesom%20APP
- aid – application id   example: aid=com.daimto.awesom.app
- av – application version  example: av=1.0.0
- aiid – Application Installer ID example: aiid=come.daimto.awesom.installer

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to +1 you but I do not yet have the 'reps'. Thanks anyway for your help..!

Comment: The documentation for the api says that aid, av, and aiid are all optional. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#apptracking

Comment: @astletron I know that but I have done testing and heard directly from the google developers those items are undocumented required items as stated.  Feel free to test yourself.  I will report the issue again to have the documentation corrected.   Welcome to stack: before down voting try and ensure that the answer is in fact wrong.

Comment: I have tested and can confirm that as of yesterday aid and aiid are not required parameters when uploading to an app property via the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol API.  Maybe the situation has changed since your discussion with those Google developers?

Comment: Could be I will add it to my list of things to retest.  But at the time the question was asked it was Undocumented required field.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking to see if you have different filters on the GA accounts it is not showing up in.  I had the same issue and it turned out to be due to an IP filter.

Comment: I had an IP filter blocking my office from where I was testing the traffic.  But real time reports process filters a bit differently than the normal GA reports as less processing can occur.  If you have any filters, it may be worth trying in one with none to see if the same occurs.

Comment: now I see what you mean. I thought you were referring to the fiters that can be created in GA. I tried modifying the latter and no difference. Account1 still show real-time events, whereas Account2 and 3 do not

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: events logged from the server are present in regular analytics, but not in real-time.
And sending the same payload with [hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) worked.

Comparing the headers sent by hit builder and my backend, I found that need to add the `user-agent` header to get the events displayed in real time view:             `"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (My App Server) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"`.